# How to find all XML elements by tag name in Groovy?

Tags: xml, groovy

How I can find all elements in XML by their tag name in Groovy (GPath)?

I need to find all `car` elements in this document:

```
<records>
  <first>
    <car>
      <id>378932</id>
    </car>
  </first>
  <second>
    <foo>
      <car>
       <name>audi</name>
      </car>
    </foo>
  </second>
</records>
```

This is what I tried and failed:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(file)
assert xml.car.size() == 2
```

Comment: id tag not closed properly

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is how it works:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(file)
def cars = xml.depthFirst().findAll { it.name() == 'car' }
assert cars.size() == 2
```

Comment: Indeed :) It took some time, but now I'm also a Grails guy :) Thanks for your help, I up-voted your answer. However the right one is mine.

Answer (score 16):

You can also do:

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parse(file)
def cars = xml.'**'.findAll { it.name() == 'car' }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use an [XMLSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlSlurper)

```
def records = new XmlSlurper().parseText(file)
reco​rds.depthFirst()​.findAll { !it.childNodes() && it.car} ​

/*Otherwise this returns the values for parent nodes as well*/
```

Comment: Google: "groovy xml slurper"

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlSlurper

Comment: Thanks guys, I know what class to use. Could you please explain how exactly I can find all elements by a given tag?

Comment: You code sample doesn't work. It returns all elements, not only `car`-s. Did you test it?