# Find function with a wildcard in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm analyzing a file as text and I need to find the first ocurrence of the value within  tags.

I've tried this:

```
def ProcessName = (stringFile =~ "<Name>\d+</Name>");
```

and this:

```
def ProcessName = (stringFile =~ "<Name>[\d+]</Name>");
```

but both throw the same error:

Script6.groovy: 45: unexpected char: '\' @ line 45, column 45. 
sName = (stringFile =~ "\d+ 
                              ^ 1 error (in groovy2 script);

Maybe I'm expressing the wildcard wrong?

This is the code in that part:

```
def stringFile = is.getText();


def ProcessName = (stringFile =~ "<Name>\d+</Name>");
```

The string is being retrieved through an input stream and contains "Test"

Comment: Are you processing XML?

Comment: Yes, I'm processing it as a string because I need to do additional processing to it, I've considered using Xpath to access it but I wanted to know if I could do it without it to avoid extra processing

Comment: Have you tried groovys built in XmlSlurper/XmlParser? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726592/how-to-find-all-xml-elements-by-tag-name-in-groovy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Processing an XML file with regex is not an ideal solution, however, to make your regex work you need to escape the backslash in your string:

```
def processName = (stringFile =~ "<Name>\\d+</Name>")
```