# How to find all elements by a tag and attribute in Groovy using XmlSlurper

Tags: xml, groovy, xml-parsing, xmlslurper

We have a xml which looks like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<GeneratorRun>
<param>
    <comGrp name="Abc">            
        <component name="A">
            <genFiles>
                <file location="xyz/a/b/x.h" checksum="1558926677"/>
                <file location="xyz/a/b/y.h" checksum="2621886660"/>                   
            </genFiles>
        </component>
        <component name="B">
            <genFiles>
                <file location=""xyz/a/b/z.h" checksum="1558926677"/>                   
            </genFiles>
        </component>
    </comGrp>
</param>
```

I need to get all file location information which are under genFiles. WHats the experession for the same.

What I tries so far is below which didn't give the result

```
GPathResult xmlContent = new XmlSlurper().parse(config.genSourceRootDir.resolve('par.xml').toFile())
  List<String> generatedFiles = xmlContent.'**'.genFiles.file.@location.toList()
```

Comment: Why do you "look" for `generatedFiles` when you want `genFiles`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all XML elements by tag name in Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726592/how-to-find-all-xml-elements-by-tag-name-in-groovy)

Comment: That was a typo. Even with genFiles I didnt get the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first find the nodes, then query their attributes

something like this:

```
List<String> generatedFiles = xmlContent.'**'
    .findAll { it.name() == 'genFiles' }
    .file*.collectMany { [it.@location] }.flatten()
```